# Webpack package.json not running

Tags: webpack

I have used webpack on a project a while ago, when i have to update the project front-end, and running scripts from package.json i get following erros, so i cannot do nothing :

```
The CLI moved into a separate package: webpack-cli.
Please install 'webpack-cli' in addition to webpack itself to use the CLI.
-> When using npm: npm install webpack-cli -D
-> When using yarn: yarn add webpack-cli -D
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! sh@1.0.0 surveiller: `webpack --watch`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the sh@1.0.0 surveiller script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely 
additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you 
mean to install?

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/XXX/.npm/_logs/2018-06-13T12_03_33_398Z- 
debug.log
```

```js
 ///// HERE IS MY package.json CONTENT
{
      "name": "sh",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "",
      "main": "index.js",
      "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
        "start": "webpack-dashboard",
        "dev": "webpack",
        "surveiller": "webpack --watch",
        "prod": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress"
      },
      "keywords": [],
      "author": "",
      "license": "ISC",
      "devDependencies": {
        "autoprefixer": "^7.2.5",
        "babel": "^6.23.0",
        "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
        "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
        "babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^6.18.0",
        "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
        "cross-env": "^5.1.3",
        "css-loader": "^0.28.9",
        "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
        "file-loader": "^1.1.6",
        "gsap": "^1.20.3",
        "node-sass": "^4.7.2",
        "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
        "postcss-loader": "^2.0.10",
        "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
        "scrollmagic": "^2.0.5",
        "style-loader": "^0.19.1",
        "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.8",
        "url-loader": "^0.6.2",
        "webpack": "^3.10.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^2.1.4",
        "webpack-dashboard": "^1.1.1",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^2.11.1"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "base64-inline-loader": "^1.1.0",
        "imports-loader": "^0.7.1",
        "instantclick": "^3.1.0-2",
        "instantclick2": "^1.1.0",
        "jquery": "^3.3.1",
        "peaks.js": "^0.9.7",
        "ritmo": "^0.5.0",
        "social-likes-next": "^1.1.0",
        "vue": "^2.5.13",
        "webpack-uglify-js-plugin": "^1.1.9",
        "youtube-iframe": "^1.0.3"
      }
    }
```

I have already used this script before and it's running well. If you could help me it will a great relief for me.

Thanks for your help

Comment: that only happens when you have webpack 4.* installed, you have webpack 3 there. Try upgrading to webpack 4.

Comment: Yes i upgraded all npm and it works now, thank you

Comment: i've added an answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The log answer your question:
-> When using npm: npm install webpack-cli -D
-> When using yarn: yarn add webpack-cli -D

Install it using npm or yarn.

Apparently one package has separated in two others.

Answer (score 0):

That only happens when you have `webpack 4.*` installed, you have `webpack 3` there.

Try upgrading to `webpack 4`. This is going to work due to the fact that `webpack` and `webpack-cli` were split into different packages.